# Property 'type' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace")'.ts(2339)

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to validate the Token from the `NodeJS(TypeScript)` Backend. In the documentation, they mentioned like this but this is in `JavaScript` I want it in `TypeScript`

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

> I want to do it in TypeScript like below using [this blog](https://medium.com/@ropupu.ropupu/use-firebase-admin-sdk-with-typescript-ae7bf7337fdd)

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin'
import * as serviceAccount from 'firebase-admin'

const params = {
  type: serviceAccount.type,
  projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
  privateKeyId: serviceAccount.private_key_id,
  privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key,
  clientEmail: serviceAccount.client_email,
  clientId: serviceAccount.client_id,
  authUri: serviceAccount.auth_uri,
  tokenUri: serviceAccount.token_uri,
  authProviderX509CertUrl: serviceAccount.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
  clientC509CertUrl: serviceAccount.client_x509_cert_url
}
   
firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(params),
})
```

but I'm getting this error,  **How can i get rid of this ?**

```
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'typeof import("nodeFirebasebackend/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace")'.ts(2339)
```

[image: error]

Comment: Based on my understanding of what you are trying to do, this doesn't seem right -> `import * as serviceAccount from 'firebase-admin'`, you already imported it in the first statement. You probably want to import the ServiceAccount type and declare it as type of your config json. const params: ServiceAccount = {//your config content}

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.serviceaccount

I can see that `serviceAccount` has the properties of

- `clientEmail`
- `privateKey`
- `projectId`

Therefore, you tried to refer a field that does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your reply? how can i give the type of other values ? any idea to resolve the issue?

Comment: @FGH I'm not a Firebase expert, but judging from the documentation and the error you had, you were simply taking the type from the wrong location. I do not know its right location though.